# how to import data from excel vb using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

Sorry for bad English
i can export data to excel file this code

```
    Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet    
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("MY EXCEL PATH")
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("SHEET1")
        With xlWorkSheet
           .Range("D8").Value = "1"
           .Range("D9").Value = "2"
        End With
        xlApp.Visible = True
```

I want to import data(D8,D9) from excel file to any text box .Can u help me? Thank

Comment: What is not working? Where are you using this code? Give some more details.

Comment: this code is work for export data to excel file only. i want to know about how to get value from excel file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Do u understand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where you want to import the data, but this should work and give you the value.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet    

Dim strOne As String    
Dim strTwo As String    

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("MY EXCEL PATH")
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("SHEET1")
With xlWorkSheet
   strOne = .Range("D8").Value  'This will give you the value of cell D8 in strOne
   strTwo = .Range("D9").Value  'This will give you the value of cell D9 in strTwo
End With

MsgBox strOne
MsgBox strTwo

'your code continue...
```

Comment: I am sorry but without proper information I can't help. Tell me where you want to use this code.